# Oracle SQL return static value if no row found in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am combining data from a couple of different tables but am running into the problem that one of the tables (sloc.export_code) sometimes contains data, sometimes is NULL, and sometimes has no entry. If it has data or is NULL then I am able to successfully retrieve the data, I am having issues if the data is not present. I would like to return MISSING if there is no row just like I am doing if the data in NULL.

Here is the statement which I have at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    THC.TRAN_HDR_CATEGORY_PK AS "DB ID",
    'PBI' AS "Order Type",
    THC.INVOICE_NUMBER AS "Invoice Number",
    supl.SUPPLY_CODE AS "Vendor Code",
    supl.supply_name AS "Vendor Name",
    LOC.location_name AS "Location Name",
    NVL(sloc.export_code, 'MISSING') AS "LOC Vendor Export Code",
    THC.INVOICE_AMOUNT AS "Invoice Amount",
    THC.ENTRY_DATE AS "Order Date",
    CASE WHEN (THC.Extract_AP_PK) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS "Exported"
 
FROM
    T_TRAN_HDR_CATEGORY THC,
    t_location loc,
    t_supply supl,
    T_SUPPLY_LOCATION sloc
    
WHERE
    THC.LOCATION_ID = LOC.location_id
    AND THC.LOCATION_ID = SLOC.LOCATION_ID
    AND supl.supply_id = THC.SUPPLY_ID
    AND THC.SUPPLY_ID = SLOC.supply_id
    AND THC.ENTRY_DATE >= SYSDATE -7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper `INNER` joins with `ON` clauses and for the table `T_SUPPLY_LOCATION` use a `LEFT` join:

```
FROM
    T_TRAN_HDR_CATEGORY THC
    INNER JOIN t_location loc ON THC.LOCATION_ID = loc.location_id
    INNER JOIN t_supply supl ON supl.supply_id = THC.SUPPLY_ID
    LEFT JOIN T_SUPPLY_LOCATION sloc ON THC.SUPPLY_ID = sloc.supply_id
WHERE
    THC.ENTRY_DATE >= SYSDATE -7
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to tweak one piece and it worked great. Much appreciated :-)